# Typing zhuyin symbols (for phonetic annotation)

Tags: zhuyin-fuhao

I want to type zhuyin symbols to add phonetic annotation.

(I can already input Chinese using Cangjie or Zhuyin inputs. )

For example, I want:
ㄓㄨˋ ㄧㄣ

The only ways I know to do this currently are:

1. Via Cangjie IME [<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>ㄓ　<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>ㄨ　<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>ˋ <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>ㄧ　<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>ㄣ]
2. via http://www.sciweavers.org/i2type/zhuyin-keyboard

I'm looking for a built-in `fcitx` keyboard or some similar native tool to type according to the zhuyin keyboard layout. (i.e. <kbd>5</kbd>ㄓ<kbd>j</kbd>ㄨ<kbd>4</kbd>ˋ <kbd>u</kbd>ㄧ<kbd>p</kbd>ㄣ

Does anyone know of one?
Thanks.

The zhuyin keyboard layout is as follows:

```
1 ㄅ
q ㄆ
a ㄇ
z ㄈ
2 ㄉ
w ㄊ
s ㄋ
x ㄌ
e ㄍ
d ㄎ
c ㄏ
r ㄐ
f ㄑ
v ㄒ
5 ㄓ
t ㄔ
g ㄕ
b ㄖ
y ㄗ
h ㄘ
n ㄙ
u ㄧ
j ㄨ
m ㄩ
8 ㄚ
i ㄛ
k ㄜ
, ㄝ
9 ㄞ
o ㄟ
l ㄠ
. ㄡ
0 ㄢ
p ㄣ
; ㄤ
/ ㄥ
- ㄦ
6 ˊ
3 ˇ
4 ˋ
7 ˙
```

see also https://askubuntu.com/posts/1358012/edit

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Linux and using fcitx, you could try rime. It's highly customizable for all languages and input methods and many awesome published input methods are ready to use ([link](https://github.com/ayaka14732/awesome-rime)).

In its default input method, type /zy, all zhuyin symbols will show up.
[image] This should satisfy non-regular use.

If you type it regularly, try the input method https://github.com/dsh0416/rime-bopomofo-symbols. If the key binding is not as you wished, you can change it in no time to whatever you want in the text file bopomofo_symbols.dict.yaml.

By the way, rime is also available on Mac and windows. On Linux, ibus is also supported, which is what I finally decided to use after exhausted all popular options.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what OS you're using.
I'm only familiar with Windows so here's how you enable it:

On Windows 10:

1. Search "Language Settings" from your Start Menu
2. Click on "Add a language"
3. Choose "Chinese(Traditional, Taiwan)
4. Wait for download to complete

[image]

You'll need to memorize the layout in mind tho if your keyboard doesn't have the zhu yin symbols printed on them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and trying to help. In my case, I can already input Chinese using 注音符號 on my system. I primarily using Cangjie 倉頡輸入法 but I was wanting to enter just the phonetic symbols themselves on a dedicated keyboard using the standard zhuyin layout. (I.e. ㄓㄨˋ　一ㄣ　ㄈㄨˊ　ㄏㄠˋ would be typed with just [5j4 up zj6 cl4] )  Currently, I have to enter these symbols using Cangjie codes倉頡碼 or modifications to my code table which is a little bit annoying. I actually created a dedicated fcitx zhuyin keyboard file, but I just don't know how to add it.

Comment: Yes, when you add the Chinese(Traditional, Taiwan) language setting, and switch your language input to that(using Windows key + space to switch), your keyboard would become the standard zhuyin (bopomofo) layout. Pressing shift once when you're on zhuyin layout can switch you between ㄅㄆㄇㄈ and 1qaz(English layout).

Comment: That's interesting. I don't have access to a Windows system but I did play around with my zhuyin Chinese IME after reading your suggestion. I was able to type ㄋㄊㄉˇㄅㄅㄆㄇㄈ by pressing the characters and space afterwards, but all vowels were converted into characters when I pressed space after them. （我隻想輸入注音的發音符號 [I only want to type the zhuyin phonetic symbols]. 我己經可以輸入漢字 [I can already enter Chinese characters] ）Thank you for your reply. I didn't know it was possible to type any Zhuyin symbols using the standard IME before your suggestion. Now if I can just figure out how to type the vowels...

Comment: Not sure how it works on your system, but usually zhuyin IMEs give you a list of characters to choose from when you enter a sequence of zhuyin. On every IME I've seen, one of the character options will always be the zhuyin characters you entered. Might have to scroll down or flip pages to see them.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I didn't realize that before, so thank you! I tried it out a bit, but it's really slow going. I'm still hoping to type zhuyin as fast as one types Russian or any other phonetic script. I mostly use Cangjie and just want to type zhuyin for phonetic annotation. I modified my Cangjie table a bit to allow me to type it faster, but I'm hoping to figure out how to make a dedicated IME to only type the phonetic symbols. Thanks again!

Comment: 我隻想輸入注音的發音符號. If you mainly use cangjie, then the presence of 隻 here is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [fcitx-chewing](https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx-chewing), a [Chewing](https://github.com/chewing) wrapper for fcitx.

You can add it as an input method within the `fcitx-configtool` or `fcitx-config-gtk3` depending on your system.